# Bootstrap tabs are shown together

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Well, I have bootstrap tabbed pane: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8273/
For some reason tabbed-content

```
<div class="tabbed-content"><div class="tab-pane active" id="journal">Journal</div><div class="tab-pane" id="photo">Photo</div><div class="tab-pane" id="video">Video</div></div>
```

Is shown without clicks. Why? What am I doing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `<div class="tab-content">` instead of `<div class="tabbed-content">`

See http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8275/

Answer (score 2):

It is not the `tabbed-content` class but instead use `tab-content`.